# how to multiply Polynomials coefficients

Tags: math, polynomials

Hello i want to know the idea of multiplying two Polynomials this function

it used to multiply the two Polynomials

i want to know what is happened in this function to the coefficients in this code

```
mul(poly((10, 20, 30)), poly((1, 2, 3))).coefs == (10, 40, 100, 120, 90)
```

how did (10, 40, 100, 120, 90) come out ?

mul() stands for the multiplying function
poly() stands for the Polynomials function

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about maths, not programming (try http://math.stackexchange.com).

Comment: no this is a  programming problem i want a mean to multiply coefs

Comment: @MohamedRamzyHelmy do you have something of code ? or no matter the language?

Comment: Try writing the multiplication out by hand for the case of two cubics, `a_3*x^2 + a_2*x^2 + a_1*x + a0`, `b_3*x^3 + b_2*x^2 + b _1*x + b0`, and keep the coefficients symbolic. The pattern should become obvious; if not, try degree 4.

Comment: i want to know if i doing multiplying what will coefs be ?

Comment: i don't have a code for it

Comment: hint : .coefs means the arguments of the function poly()

Comment: Which programming language are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you multiply polynomial A of Nth power with polynomial B by Mth power, you'll get resulting polynomial C of (N+M) power, which has N+M+1 coefficients. Kth coefficient of result:

`C[k]{k=0..N+M} = Sum(A[i] * B[k - i]){find proper range for i}`

example for N = 3 and M = 3:

`C[5] = A[3]*B[2] + A[2]*B[3]`

I hope that implementation of such a simple formula with cycle is not problem in any programming language.

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume your coefficients are stored in two an arrays A[], B[] in with coeff[0] being the zero-th degree term and store the result in C.

```
// degree of result
int deg=A.length+B.length-2;
int C[] = new int[deg+1];
// initialise to zero
for(i=0;i<=deg;++i) {
    C[i]=0;
}
for(i=0;i<A.length;++i) {
    for(j=0;j<B.length;++j) {
        C[i+j] += A[i] * B[j];
    }
}
```